# Meaning of JSON Error I am getting

Tags: android, json

I am new to android programming .Help me in interpreting the errors . Is there any problem with web service I am using . I am using web services in Login and registration Page .

```
 04-04 01:45:09.939: W/System.err(1463): org.json.JSONException: Value yes of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
    04-04 01:45:09.979: W/System.err(1463):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
    04-04 01:45:09.979: W/System.err(1463):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
    04-04 01:45:09.979: W/System.err(1463):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
    04-04 01:45:09.979: W/System.err(1463):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$SigIn.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:145)
    04-04 01:45:09.979: W/System.err(1463):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$SigIn.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
    04-04 01:45:09.979: W/System.err(1463):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    04-04 01:45:09.999: W/System.err(1463):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    04-04 01:45:09.999: W/System.err(1463):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    04-04 01:45:09.999: W/System.err(1463):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    04-04 01:45:09.999: W/System.err(1463):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    04-04 01:45:10.009: W/System.err(1463):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here is my code:-

```
private class SigIn extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
        ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(final String... params) 
        {
            ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                try 
                {
                    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait signing in...");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            pDialog.show();
                        }
                    });

                    JSONObject job= new JSONObject();
                    euid = uedit.getText().toString();
                    epass = pedit.getText().toString();

                    euid.replace("" ,"%20");
                    epass.replace("" ,"%20");


                    job.put("status_key","2");
                    job.put("method", "login");
                    job.put("email", euid);
                    job.put("password",epass );

                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(job.toString());

                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/mobileapp_now/webservice.php");

                    httppost.setEntity(se);

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                    System.out.println("response "+data);

                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("user_details");

                    for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        System.out.println("please print my name...for....");
                        try {


                                JSONObject jsob = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                // Pulling items from the array
                                //uid = jsob.getString("id");
                                mfname = jsob.getString("first_name");
                                msname = jsob.getString("surname");
                                mun = jsob.getString("unit_no");
                                mstreet = jsob.getString("street_name");
                                msuburb = jsob.getString("suburb");
                                mstate = jsob.getString("state");
                                mpassword = jsob.getString("password");
                                mpostcode = jsob.getString("post_code");
                                mlicense = jsob.getString("driving_license");
                                mid = job.getString("authority_id");
                                mmobile = jsob.getString("mobile_no");
                                memail = jsob.getString("email");


                               System.out.println(mpassword+".....please print my name......."+mpassword);
                               System.out.println(uid+"......please print my name......."+mfname);
                               System.out.println(mstate +"......please print my name......."+mlicense);
                               System.out.println(mmobile+"........please print my customertype......."+memail);

                         } catch (JSONException e) {

                        } 
                    }
                            if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("0"))
                    {
                        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                        alert.setTitle("Login!!!");
                        alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) 
                            {
                                pDialog.dismiss();


                                dialog.dismiss();

                                Intent tabint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);


                                startActivity(tabint);
                        }
                        });
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                alert.show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                        alert.setTitle("Alert !");
                        alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                dialog.dismiss();

                            }
                        });
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                        {
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                pDialog.dismiss();

                                alert.show();
                            }
                        });
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return params;
        }
```

JSON code for both login and Registration page:-

```
function login($data) 
{
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($data -> email);

    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($data -> password);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * from driver_register where Email='$email' and password=md5('$password')");

    if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
    {
        $token = mysql_real_escape_string(generateRandomString(150));

        mysql_query("Update driver_register set login_token='$token' where id='{$row['id']}'");
        if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) 
        {   
            return array("message" => "Login successful.", "token"=>$token,"err-code" => "0");
        }
        else 
        {
            return array("message" => "Server is under progress.", "err-code" => "500", "error" => mysql_error());
        }


    }
    else 
    {
        return array("message" => "Username and Password does not match. Kindly try again.", "err-code" => "300", "err" => mysql_error() . $sql);
    }
}


function driver_register($data)
{
    $fname      = mysql_real_escape_string($data->first_name);
    $password       = mysql_real_escape_string($data->password);
    $sname      = mysql_real_escape_string($data->surname);
    $unit       = mysql_real_escape_string($data->unit_no);
    $street     = mysql_real_escape_string($data->street_name);
    $suburb     = mysql_real_escape_string($data->suburb);
    $state      = mysql_real_escape_string($data->state);
    $post_code  = mysql_real_escape_string($data->post_code);
    $dr_lic     = mysql_real_escape_string($data->driving_license);
    $authority_id  = mysql_real_escape_string($data->authority_id);
    $mobile_no  = mysql_real_escape_string($data->mobile_no);
    $email      = mysql_real_escape_string($data->email);

    $lic        = $data -> license_pic;
    $audit      = $data -> audit_card_pic;
    $face   = $data -> face_pic;

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM driver_register where Email='$email'");
    $ans = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    if(empty($ans))
    {

        $sql="INSERT INTO `driver_register`(`password`,`first_name`, `Surname`, `unit_no`, `street_name`, `Suburb`, `State`, `post_code`, `driving_lic`, `authority_id`, `mobile_no`, `Email`, `date_of_creation`) VALUES (md5('$password'),'$fname','$sname','$unit','$street','$suburb','$state','$post_code','$dr_lic','$authority_id','$mobile_no','$email',NOW())";
        //echo $sql;
        mysql_query($sql);

        if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
                    $image_lic = base64_decode($lic);
                    $image_audit = base64_decode($audit);
                    $image_face = base64_decode($face);

                    $i_id = mysql_insert_id();

                    file_put_contents("upload/license_". $i_id . ".png", $image_lic);
                    $path_driver = mysql_real_escape_string("upload/license_" . $i_id . ".png");

                    file_put_contents("upload/audit_" . $i_id . ".png", $image_audit);
                    $path_audit = mysql_real_escape_string("upload/audit_" . $i_id . ".png");

                    file_put_contents("upload/face_" . $i_id . ".png", $image_face);
                    $path_face = mysql_real_escape_string("upload/face_" . $i_id . ".png");

                    mysql_query("UPDATE `driver_register` SET `license_pic`='$path_driver',`audit_card_pic`='$path_audit',`face_pic`='$path_face' WHERE `id`='$i_id'");

                }


        if(mysql_affected_rows()>0)
        {
            return array("err-code"=>"0","message"=>"Registration Successfully");   
        }
        else
        {
            return array("err-code"=>"404","message"=>"Registration not successfull");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return array("err-code"=>"1","message"=>"Email-Id Already Exist");
    }
}
```

after truncating yes from response:-

```
04-04 04:13:54.219: D/response(2034): {
04-04 04:13:54.219: D/response(2034):     "message": "Login successful.",
04-04 04:13:54.219: D/response(2034):     "token": "cE5J09FgZCxlyWLcJpHik1ttBcP02p8e4eY4oElngSJPOu1yUIQeKjIlvxlyXuM1IL66pruGkdv9IxHCgyR0Rzln7HV4cI6Utc1TEwzYK58tCP5TnXTfwfDEXzI9hO4L16EFDeEnjMQWCWP0TJgqZT",
04-04 04:13:54.219: D/response(2034):     "err-code": "0"
04-04 04:13:54.219: D/response(2034): }
04-04 04:13:54.229: W/System.err(2034): org.json.JSONException: No value for user_details
04-04 04:13:54.229: W/System.err(2034):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
04-04 04:13:54.229: W/System.err(2034):     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:549)
04-04 04:13:54.239: W/System.err(2034):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$SigIn.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:150)
04-04 04:13:54.239: W/System.err(2034):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$SigIn.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
04-04 04:13:54.239: W/System.err(2034):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-04 04:13:54.249: W/System.err(2034):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-04 04:13:54.249: W/System.err(2034):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-04 04:13:54.249: W/System.err(2034):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-04 04:13:54.259: W/System.err(2034):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-04 04:13:54.259: W/System.err(2034):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Post your JSON and your code. One of the two is wrong.

Comment: Why don't you log the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert a string to a JSONObject you need to do something like:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{a string}");
```

Update:
How does `data` looks like?

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);
```

Maybe you need to add curly brackets:

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject("{" + data + "}");
```

Comment: The code written in the last is created by my friend as web services. I am confused that whether I have implemented them correctly or not.

Comment: enclosing the string within curly brackets isn't making any difference.

Comment: Where is line 145? What's the value of `data`?

Comment: JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);

Comment: String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

Comment: OK, what is the value of `data`? Please set a breakpoint and check what EntityUtils gives back.

Comment: 04-04 03:37:15.399: I/System.out(1860): response yes {"message":"Login successful.","token":"bSHsG1GzSrH1xTZfcQyJR4hCrqviqszCkh40iLAbchcKbb0n2y6TDnw4O1‌​nfuWROeWPxHpIUHUFS6Fg8em1RKyVzAiO4fGTtCJ1k8JfQDVJJBZSPmUH6sDF2Wu7ba1FNKG8TqnJ4jtO‌​UsGJOArV34B","err-code":"0"}

Comment: OK, truncate your string and pass on only the curly brackets part.

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit more . I am not getting you .

Comment: get a substring of your string (e.g. {"message" ... "err-code":"0"}) and pass this substring on. The substring has to be in curly brackets.

Comment: After doing this I am getting some issues again .Please see the post > I have added the logcat of it .

Comment: It's not the same. You later try to access "user_details" `JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("user_details");` but "user_details" doesn't exist. So either add it first, check if it exist or don't try to read it.

Comment: * I wrote some not same. Anyhow,  Thanks a lot for your help . Your idea worked.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that you try to access a JSON string value as a JSON Object.

Comment: The code written in the last is created by my friend as web services. I am confused that whether I have implemented them correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code and json response,
In this scenario you can try to convert String to jsonObject.

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(responseWeb);// responseWeb is String variable and you can convert string  to JsonObject like this.
```

Comment: The code written in the last is created by my friend as web services. I am confused that whether I have implemented them correctly or not.

Comment: hi, can you please share response text of web service.

Comment: 04-04 03:37:15.399: I/System.out(1860): response yes {"message":"Login successful.","token":"bSHsG1GzSrH1xTZfcQyJR4hCrqviqszCkh40iLAbchcKbb0n2y6TDnw4O1nfuWROeWPxHpIUHUFS6Fg8em1RKyVzAiO4fGTtCJ1k8JfQDVJJBZSPmUH6sDF2Wu7ba1FNKG8TqnJ4jtOUsGJOArV34B","err-code":"0"}

Comment: The problem is the `yes` that comes before the JSON object.

Comment: OK,

Web service response is JsonObject, in jsonobject have three string, like message, token, err-code.

So you can retrive this String like this,

JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(responseWeb);

String message=jsonObject.optString("message"); //message string
String message=jsonObject.optString("token"); //message token
String message=jsonObject.optString("err-code"); //error -code string

Comment: @Henry after removing yes I am getting some error again . Please check the updated post.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert a JSONString to JSONObject somewhere here in your code:

com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$SigIn.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:145)

Or you can use JSONTokener:

```
Object json = new JSONTokener(data).nextValue();
if (json instanceof JSONObject)
 //you have an object
else if (json instanceof JSONArray)
 //you have an array
```

Comment: The code written in the last is created by my friend as web services. I am confused that whether I have implemented them correctly or not.

Comment: You should check for the JSON, in case the format has changed since the last JSON parser implemented by your friend.  If the format has changed then you should do so accordingly in your code i.e . where it is crashing currently.  If there is a probability that the response can be either String or JSONObject or may be some other type then it would be wise to add a Type check before extracting out the information.

Comment: I need to know whether I am using the correct web services .And whether I have used them correctly or not .

Comment: I can not help you with web services.  But if you can post the JSON response you are sending to the application, I can help you in figuring out if the JSON parsing is being done correctly or not by the application.

Comment: I am using Log.d("response", jo.toString(4)); to print the response at the logcat but its not showing up there.

Comment: Print the HTTPResponse.

Comment: @ Keya Thanks for your concern. I have sorted out the problem